Getting MYOB.AccountRight Access Code error
I am currently trying to get the access code from MYOB Accountright Online via API call. What I did so far is:
[HttpGet("api/[controller]")]
public RedirectResult Connect()
{
    
    var rr = new RedirectResult(_myobService.MYOBCloudAPIURL());
    
    return rr;
}

[HttpGet("api/[controller]/callback")]
public IActionResult Callback(string? code, string? state)
{
    return CustomResult(code, StatusCodes.Status200OK);
}

In which MYOBCloudAPIURL() is a string combining the required params for MYOB Get Access Code request. The URI is currently looking like this:
https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/account/authorize/?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a7098%2fapi%2fMYOB%2fcallback&scope=CompanyFile&response_type=code

From the documentation I believe after successful authentication it should redirect to my callback endpoint. However at the moment after login in it redirects to MYOB wepage that has invalid_request error message. I look at the network log and it has the https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/Account/LoginCallBack POST request with status code 302. I'm not sure what the issue currently is?
